# Validation not working using @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Posted, Model.Posted = DateTime.Now)
```

But the validation does not work It crashes when I run my application and try to edit or create an item.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new NewsItem());
}
```

I also have the following code above in my controller and the application it all works to what I want it do for example it inputs the current date and saves it but if I leave one editor box blank or a all the editor box's blank the application crashes and gives the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I do not know what this means? I thought the default validation provided by MVC3 C# should work? So what is wrong? Can anyone help?

```
/* This line of code is what is provided for validation it is pretty much 
   similar on all the edit, delete and create views. */
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Posted)
```

Comment: When you see anything that states Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.. that means that you are trying to access an object that has not been instantiated.. can you post the code where you are getting the exact error .. where is NewsItem being declared for example...

Comment: where you state that if you leave one or all objects blank you will need to do some null checking there as well

Comment: I shall post the code thank you for your help

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Posted, Model.Posted = DateTime.Now) this is where I am getting the error in the view

Comment: can you do DateTime.Now.ToString(); what is the DataType of the Model.Posted expecting..

Comment: I have not added any DataType I shall try the .ToString and report back thank you

Comment: Your code in your @Html.HiddenFor is a little strange. Why are you using it like that?

Comment: I have added the following DateTime.Now.ToString(); and it says Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Date.Time'

Comment: @James user is already doing that... passing a new instance to the create view. See the code user has posted.

Comment: You need to tell us what code exactly is causing the exception. I doubt it is any of the code that has been discussed here so far.

Comment: "Object reference not set..." is somewhat of a useless error message. Post the stacktrace of the error, too.

Answer (score 5):

Your second argument to Html.HiddenFor looks wrong. If you want to set the value, try this instead:

```
@{
    Model.Posted = DateTime.Now;
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Posted)
```

Or better yet, set the value in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new NewsItem { Posted = DateTime.Now });
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Posted)
```

**Update after comment 2**

What date is being input? What should the correct date be? Your question stated a problem with a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). You may have to post the code for your NewsItem model for anyone to help you further.

**Update after comment 4**

I do not see where any of the code I offered change any application functionality. And if you don't understand what a `NullReferenceException` is, it sounds like you haven't been programming for very long. So I will take your stab at my incorrectness with a grain of salt.

A NullReferenceException has nothing to do with validation, really. It happens when you try to invoke a method, property, or other member on a variable that references null. Consider the following:

```
var myVariable = "Hello, world";
if (DateTime.Now.Year > 2011)
{
    myVariable = null;
}
var anotherVariable = myVariable.Substring(1);
```

Before Sunday, this code would have worked just fine. But as soon as the clock switches over to 2012 in your time zone, it will start to throw a NullReferenceException. Why? Because when the year is 2012 (or greater), your code will essentially be doing this:

```
null.SubString(1);
```

If this doesn't help you figure out where your NullReferenceException is coming from, then we're going to need to call in a psychic. Unless, of course, you post some more code.

Comment: I shall try that and let you know

Comment: The date which is current it inputted the correct date but yours does not

Comment: Well the whole purpose for me to post my problem so I can receive help but fixing one problem by changing the applications function is not correct. Thank you for all help

Comment: I understand what null reference means as in when the database has set to no nulls so when you try to input a null it crashes and gives an error and it has got something to do with validation as all I wanted was to know how can that be validated so when some one try to enter a null it shows a message saying ok you have put nothing in while keeping.@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Posted, Model.Posted = DateTime.Now) so if everything is edited correctly the date that it was edited is shown. Your code that you have provided does work for the create fine but not the edit. Thank you for the help

Comment: why not set the PostedDate on the model, in the controller, before you pass it through to the View? Then, once it's populated in the view, it has the value

Comment: I have tried the following:   

public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            using (var db = new UniversityNewsEntities1())
            {

And the following in my view:

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Posted)

For the edit but it only works 50/50 as in it does edit the information but it edits all of it because the information when you click on edit is all blank there is nothing to edit it just replaces all the information
                return View(new NewsItem { Posted = DateTime.Now });
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple:

- Remove any reference to Model.Posted in your view,
- Set the Posted property to DateTime.Now() in your Post Create action in the controller.

Comment: My create works fine the DateTime.Now works fine in create it is edit that I am having problems with thanks

Comment: The answer stays the same for editing your NewsItem. Set the Posted property in the Post Edit action.